# MVC3 Stop Model Values From Being Set By The Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model

Not a major question but definitely one that would be a nice one to see fixed.

I have, for example, a model that looks like this (not I cut out some to save reading time, i do have confirm fields etc :) ):

```
public class NewUser
{
    [Required]
    public string Username{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password{ get; set; }

    public string Salt{ get; set; }
}
```

In my code after post (after validation) I create a salt that is used to one way encrypt the password, and it is very useful to have it in the model (I know I can leave it out but I would rather not).

If, on post, the user adds to their querystring `&salt=blahblahblah`, as soon as the page is posted back and MVC matches up the model, it assigns the value `blahblahblah` to my model as expected, I haven't got a problem with this as I can always override this.

Is there any way that I can have an attribute that will make MVC not assign a value in a model to what was sent from the postback as there are some values in other models that I do not want it to have the possibility to set (I have my workarounds to reset them to what they should have been, but missing this could cause problems if someone wanted to attempt to hack in some values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx) to white/blacklist properties during the modelbinding:

You can apply it on the Model level globally:

```
[Bind(Exclude="Salt")]
public class NewUser
{
    [Required]
    public string Username{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password{ get; set; }

    public string Salt{ get; set; }
}
```

Or on the individual controller action level:

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Bind(Exclude="Salt")] NewUser user)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly! I didn't expect a correct answer this fast, I can't even accept it yet. Do you know of any way to do it per property of that model, such as adding `[Exclude]` above the `Salt` instead of a comma list at the top? There isn't a problem with using that method, just trying to get a full picture of the methods to do it.

Comment: No, you can only use it on the class or on the action method parameter level with the comma separated property list. You need to extend the model binding if you want to have a new attribute which can be applied on property level.

Comment: No point in creating something if it already exists in another form, thanks for that, never heard of that method myself :)